# How to get sorted records from a given start point

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In table there are too many records, but i want to get records chunk by chunk and also sorted by first name. some of the records have first name in lower case and some in upper case. In first request i am getting 1st 20 sorted records, this works fine, but in load more request i want to get next 20 records starting from the particular id, this id is the id of the last record in the first chunk. in that case my query goes wrong it gives me repeated data.

```
    contact.find({'_id': {'$gt': req.params.last_id}})    
      .sort({first_name: 1}).limit(20).exec(function(error, list) { 
                        if (error)
                         res.send(error)
                          res.json(list) });
```

this query gives me some records that should not be in that chunk.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the skip method](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/)

```
contact.find({}).sort({first_name: 1}).skip(20).limit(20)
```

Comment: this just skips my records, i don't want that,